# Setting text of a UITextField does not update UI, until it gets focus | iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a few custom UITextFields inside a scrollview. I'm setting textfield's text programmatically. But the text is not visible until it gets focus

This is how I set the text:

```
[self.textfield setText:@"+998 "];
```

This is my custom textfield:

```
@implementation BottomBorderedTF{
    CALayer* bottomLine;
    CGColorRef borderColor;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    borderColor = [UIColor colorNamed:@"ofb_blue"].CGColor;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews{
    bottomLine = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    borderColor = [UIColor colorNamed:@"ofb_blue"].CGColor;
    bottomLine.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.frame.size.height - 1, self.frame.size.width, 1.0);
    bottomLine.backgroundColor = borderColor;
    self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    [self.layer addSublayer:bottomLine];
}

- (void)showError:(BOOL)hasError{
    if (hasError) {
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor.CGColor;
    } else {
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = borderColor;
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: have you tried setting the text on the main thread?